# Site Variation limit in SP2010?

Tags: variations, language

does anyone know if the limit on variations (50 labels) in SharePoint 2007 is the same in SP2010?

have anyone worked with variations in SP2010 yet and have some knowledge to share?

Anders Rask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported limit is still 50 in SP 2010